# Installing and using universal-ctags instead of exuberant-ctags

Tags: 16.04, c++

How could I switch from exuberant-ctags to [universal-ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags). I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and

`ctags --version` reports

`Exuberant Ctags 5.9~svn20110310, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is simple, as in the [universal-ctags docs](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/blob/master/docs/autotools.rst):

```
git clone https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags.git
cd ctags
./autogen.sh 
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: where does it get installed?

Comment: @gregghz /usr/local/bin/ctags in my case

Comment: In case you want to avoid `sudo` and install in your user directory, use `./configure --prefix=$HOME` (then, no need for sudo for `make install`).

Comment: Also one tip is to use checkinstall, i.e `sudo checkinstall make install` this will create a DEB package (or the equivalent for your distro) to make it easier to uninstall/reinstall.

Comment: "It is simple", no it isn't. I have a stock Ubuntu 16 LTS, when you run `autogen.sh` you get `autoreconf: not found`. 'Simple' is running a deb file.

Comment: To fix the `autoreconf` error, you need `sudo apt install autoconf`. It is now an offical debian package: https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/issues/655#issuecomment-377423868

Comment: I had to install `automake` and `pkg-config` before running `./autogen.sh` on ubuntu 18.x

Answer (score 14):

I'm on Ubuntu, and for me I can use either:

```
sudo apt install universal-ctags
```

or

```
sudo snap install universal-ctags
```

The snap has the advantage that it will work on any Ubuntu release (or on any other distribution with snapd installed.)

I manage this snap package, and currently (June 2022) make releases from the universal-ctags source every two weeks. So the snap is a lot more up-to-date (May 2022) than the apt (currently September 2021, on Jammy).

The snap has some disadvantages imposed by the snap security model (snaps run in a container, and are only granted access to specific aspects of the underlying host), so for example the snap of universal-tags cannot run on source code that is outside of your home folder. These limitations are described in detail on [the snap listing page](https://snapcraft.io/universal-ctags), but shouldn't be intrusive for the vast majority of normal use.

I've been happily using the snap version professionally for over two years now.

Comment: in ubuntu 16.04: `$ sudo snap install universal-ctags` works though!

Comment: Yes, the same snap works in all (versions of) all distribution, and the snap's functionality is slowly improving as I throw more fixes in. I now use it daily, with no problems.

Comment: `sudo apt install universal-ctags` doesn't work on ubuntu 22.04 `E: Unable to locate package universal-ctags`